# Javafx TableView scroll issue with arrow keys

Tags: javafx, scroll, tableview, arrow-keys

I am using JavaFX 11.  I have a TableView with a list of mp3 files.  While scrolling with arrow keys I am seeing what I think is odd behavior.  When I get to the last 'viewable' item in my TableView and hit the down arrow key the focused row jumps up several rows, instead of just one.  I have included an image to show what I am trying to explain.
I've added some code which does not match the images I posted but the behavior is exactly the same.

[image]

---

```java
public class FXMLController implements Initializable {

    @FXML
    private TableView<Person> tableView;

    @Override
    public void initialize(URL url, ResourceBundle rb) {
        TableColumn<Person, String> col1 = new TableColumn<>("Column 1");
        col1.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<Person, String>("firstName"));
        tableView.getColumns().add(col1);

        TableColumn<Person, String> col2 = new TableColumn<>("Column 2");
        col2.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<Person, String>("lastName"));
        tableView.getColumns().add(col2);

        List<Person> list = new ArrayList<Person>();
        for (int x = 0; x < 50; x++) {
            Person p = new Person();
            p.setFirstName("First Name "+x);
            p.setLastName("Last Name "+x);
            list.add(p);
        }
        ObservableList<Person> observableList = FXCollections.observableList(list);
        tableView.setItems(observableList);
    }
```

Scene.fxml:

```xml
<VBox prefHeight="400.0" prefWidth="640.0" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/11.0.1" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="com.mycompany.tableviewtest.FXMLController">
   <children>
      <TableView fx:id="tableView" />
   </children>
</VBox>
```

Comment: Can you show us (some of) your code? Then, maybe, we can help?

Comment: it's a [bug fixed in fx13](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8197536)